# Peeking into an iterator

Tags: kotlin, iterator, sequence, guava

Is there a way in Kotlin to "peek" into the next element of an iterator without advancing it? For an example use case, consider this function for merging two pre-sorted sequences:

```
fun merge(seq1: Sequence<Int>, seq2: Sequence<Int>) = sequence<Int> {
    val it1 = seq1.iterator()
    var current1 = if (it1.hasNext()) it1.next() else null
    val it2 = seq2.iterator()
    var current2 = if (it2.hasNext()) it2.next() else null

    while (current1 != null && current2 != null) {
        if (current1 <= current2) {
            yield(current1)
            current1 = if (it1.hasNext()) it1.next() else null
        } else {
            yield(current2)
            current2 = if (it2.hasNext()) it2.next() else null
        }
    }
    while (current1 != null) {
        yield(current1)
        current1 = if (it1.hasNext()) it1.next() else null
    }
    while (current2 != null) {
        yield(current2)
        current2 = if (it2.hasNext()) it2.next() else null
    }
}
```

This function has to jump through hoops because the `Iterator` interface has no way of asking for the next element without advancing it. In other words, it doesn't respect the [Command-Query Separation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

I can make this function much more concise and readable if I use Guava's [PeekingIterator](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/PeekingIterator.html):

```
fun merge(seq1: Sequence<Int>, seq2: Sequence<Int>) = sequence<Int> {
    val it1: PeekingIterator<Int> = Iterators.peekingIterator(seq1.iterator())
    val it2: PeekingIterator<Int> = Iterators.peekingIterator(seq2.iterator())

    while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext())
        yield((if (it1.peek() <= it2.peek()) it1 else it2).next())
    yieldAll(it1)
    yieldAll(it2)
}
```

The same functionality reduced from 24 lines to 9 lines! However, I feel uncomfortable using Guava in a Kotlin project. Guava was created to address some of the Java API's limitations. The Kotlin standard library is much richer, and we shouldn't need to use a third-party Java library. Is there a way to make the first code sample much more concise and readable without using Guava?

**Appendix**

Here's a sample unit test for the above function, which should give you an idea of how it should behave:

```
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.FreeSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe

class MyTest : FreeSpec({
    "merge test" {
        merge(emptySequence(), emptySequence()).toList() shouldBe emptyList()
        merge(emptySequence(), sequenceOf(1)).toList() shouldBe listOf(1)
        merge(emptySequence(), sequenceOf(1, 3)).toList() shouldBe listOf(1, 3)
        merge(sequenceOf(1), emptySequence()).toList() shouldBe listOf(1)
        merge(sequenceOf(1, 3), emptySequence()).toList() shouldBe listOf(1, 3)
        merge(sequenceOf(0, 3, 4), sequenceOf(1, 4, 7)).toList() shouldBe listOf(0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 7)
    }
)
```

Comment: It's good that you have a function showing what you're trying to do, but can we get a main with feeder input? I have an idea, but before I give it as an answer I want to make sure I reproduce your exact case

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno I've written a unit test that should show you how the function is expect to behave.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think Kotlin stdlib provides this, but we can implement it by ourselves:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val iter = listOf(1, 2, 3).iterator().peeking()

    println(iter.next()) // 1
    println(iter.peek()) // 2
    println(iter.peek()) // 2
    println(iter.next()) // 2
    println(iter.peek()) // 3
    println(iter.next()) // 3
    println(iter.peek()) // NoSuchElementException
}

fun <T> Iterator<T>.peeking() = object : PeekingIterator<T> {
    private var hasPeeked = false
    private var peeked: T? = null

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean = hasPeeked || this@peeking.hasNext()

    override fun next(): T  {
        return if (hasPeeked) {
            hasPeeked = false
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            peeked as T
        } else {
            this@peeking.next()
        }
    }

    override fun peek(): T {
        if (!hasPeeked) {
            peeked = this@peeking.next()
            hasPeeked = true
        }
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return peeked as T
    }
}

interface PeekingIterator<T> : Iterator<T> {
    fun peek(): T
}
```

Comment: I like your use of `as T` to make the result non-nullable instead of using `!!` which would add unnecessary checks in the bytecode. It would be nice if it were possible to say, via Contracts, that "hasPeeked == true implies peeked != null" which would then make the cast (and warning suppression) unnecessary.

Comment: @k314159 I believe using `!!` would be actually incorrect. If `T` is nullable then null is a valid value for `T` and we should return it :-) We use `T?` and then cast to `T` mostly to support the case when `T` is not nullable, but we still have to store null initially. There are alternative solutions that maybe would be cleaner on handling the `T`.

Comment: You're right, we can't use `!!`. To avoid having to repeat the suppressions, I've pulled the common code to a getter and made it `T` instead of `T?` in my new answer.

Comment: Just found a small issue: if the iterator has gone past all elements, and you call `peek()` and catch the expected `NoSuchElementException`, if you then call `hasNext()` it returns `true` when it should return `false`. You can fix that by moving the line `hasPeeked = true` to after the following line.

Comment: @k314159 Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've written and used a more concise version of [broot's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77174504/13963086):

```
interface PeekingIterator<T> : Iterator<T> {
    fun peek(): T
}

fun <T> Iterator<T>.peeking(): PeekingIterator<T> =
    if (this is PeekingIterator)
        this
    else
        object : PeekingIterator<T> {
            private var cached = false

            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            private var element: T = null as T
                get() {
                    if (!cached)
                        field = this@peeking.next()
                    return field
                }

            override fun hasNext(): Boolean = cached || this@peeking.hasNext()

            override fun next(): T = element.also { cached = false }

            override fun peek(): T = element.also { cached = true }
        }
```

Comment: If you already went this approach, then I think your `element get()` is pretty much... peek operation. And `next()` is basically a peek + reset the boolean. You can move the code of property to `peek()`, add `cached = true` there, then `next() = peek().also { cached = false }`. I like the `null as T` part - this is better than making the property `T?`.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: You can eliminate the `isPeeked` property like in the deleted answer by using `this` to represent no value. https://pl.kotl.in/mjTRHr1ND Though I suppose it could theoretically break if `T` is Any and the original iterator was a MutableIterator that was used to add its own peeking wrapper to itelf. :/

Comment: @Tenfour04 It would be better to use `===`/`!==` when comparing to `this` ;-) Especially, because we invoke unknown `equals()` here.

Comment: I love the discussion! Many nice ideas :-)